# How do I understand html page dimensions?

Tags: javascript, html, viewport, document-body

It's been a mystery for me since day one. And it still is. The time has come to reveal it. So I've made a [test page](https://jsfiddle.net/64j43vnh/1/), containing a `div`, which extents you can change. And info panel that displays values of relevant properties. Let's take just Chrome for simplicity.

[image]
[image]

Default `body` margin is `8px`. `html`'s background is blue, `body`'s green, and `div` is of red color. And here we can see that `html`'s `offsetHeight` is equal to `body.offsetHeight + 2 * body.margin`, as if it just envelopes `body`. But `html.clientHeight` == `window.innerHeight`, as if it's stretched to fill the viewport.

Now let's add horizontal scrollbar (make `div`'s width `1000px`), and scroll to the right a bit:

[image]
[image]

`html` and `body` move to the left. `body`'s `scrollLeft` changes in sync with `window.pageXOffset` as if it owns the scrollbar. `html`'s `clientHeight` changed owing to the added scrollbar.

Let's do it the other way around (vertical scrollbar):

[image]
[image]

Now both `html`'s extents changed (`offsetWidth` and `clientWidth`). Which suggests it doesn't own the scrollbar.

And finally, with both scrollbars:

[image]
[image]

Well, at this point things are more or less [clear](http://hwrnmnbsol.livejournal.com/148664.html) to me. At least as long as we're only considering Chrome. But there are still a couple of things I'd like know.

- How come `html`'s `clientHeight` can possibly be less then `offsetHeight`? Is there any better explanation than "it's just so"?
- Why `body`'s `scrollLeft`/`scrollTop` changes as I scroll the page? It doesn't own the scrollbars, does it?

Also some summary would be in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there's a canvas that is displayed in a viewport (window). On the canvas we have `html` element, which contains `body`. They're mostly like `div`s, but have some quirks:

- Along the X axis `html` element by default (`width: auto`) stretches to fit viewport. Not a quirk probably. Viewport is `html`'s container. And as an ordinary `div` it by default fits container width (excluding scrollbar).
- `html`'s height is as big as to fit `body` element. But for some reason its `clientHeight` equals to viewport height minus scrollbar. As if it stretches to fit viewport along the Y axis as well.
- `body`'s `scrollLeft`/`scrollTop` properties mirror viewport's `pageXOffset`/`pageYOffset`
- `body`'s top margin doesn't collapse with `html`'s one
- `body` shows no signs of stretching to the bottom edge of the viewport unless you have, e.g., absolutely positioned element with `bottom` property being set. Judging from `offsetParent` value, `body` acts as an element, relative to which absolutely positioned elements are rendered by default (unless there are other absolutely positioned elements up the hierarchy)

With Firefox the difference is that it's `html`'s `scrollLeft`/`scrollTop` properties that mirror viewport's `pageXOffset`/`pageYOffset`.

That all is just my interpretation of what I see. I'd be glad if someone were to correct me, or add to my findings.